# Facebook share link on page

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a share as page(/page-id/feed) of a link with a picture (the link can be associated with any picture).

But the OG tags take over the control of the image, rather the data sent by the api.

I tried to hide the OG tags and the tags (description etc...) that can help Facebook to take the targeted pages information, with a extra URL parameter, but it doesn't work...

I just need to share a link on a page with a picture not defined by the targeted page.

Thanks for reading I hope you have understand, and then you can help me.

Comment: why would you want to do that? facebook specifically removed this possibility, because people should know what to expect behind the link - with the original og tags.

Comment: I don't recall eve reading that it was possible to send a unique set of OG data with a share link. What URL parameters did you try?

Comment: Finaly it was what i did, but that was hard for the cache.